# Adobe Flash file names

Tags: adobe, flash

I have some Windows 2012 R2 machines which come with inbuilt support for Adobe Flash in my lab. On some systems, Flash.ocx & FlashUtil_Activex.dll, while on some systems I have NPSWF64_xx_x_xxx_xxx.dll & NPSWF32_xx_x_xxx_xxx.dll.

Does anyone know if even though HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}\InprocServer32 points to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash folder, why is there a difference in the flash player file names - flashutil.dll & npswf.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Here is what I found - 
FlashUtil_Activex.dll is the ActiveX Control used by IE.  On Windows 2012, this is integrated in IE and all updates come from Microsoft, and therefore, no version number listed in the file name. NPSWF64_x.dll & NPSWF32_x.dll are the NPAPI plugins used by Firefox and other NPAPI-compatible browsers which are not interchangeable. The ActiveX Control only works with IE/Edge. The NPAPI plugin only works with Firefox and NPAPI-compatible browsers (such as Safari, etc), and the PPAPI plugin (which you don't mention) is only compatible with Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, etc). HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}\InprocServer32 is used by the ActiveX Control and not the NPAPI or PPAPI plugins.